Problem updating Debian Bookworm
After reading many other related entries my specific problem has not been solved yet.
Running sudo apt-get update ultimately results in
Get:31 http://deb.debian.org/ debian bookworm-updates/non-free-firmware Translation-en [384 B]
Fetched 24.4 MB in 8s (3.023 kB/s)

Reading package lists ... Error!

E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/dpkg/status (1)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package cache file is corrupted

Clearing part of the cache using
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*bookworm-updates

results in the same problem.
Where is this going wrong? What should I be doing instead? Thanks for your time in advance.

filesystem getting full? Else, you should do a preventive backup of both /var/lib/dpkg/status and /var/lib/dpkg/status-old (which might be not corrupted) elsewhere.

Could you [edit] your question to show the output of ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/status*?

I see no indication that the bookword-updates repo is involved, so I don't see any point in restricting the cache cleaning to that. If you show the complete output of apt update (it's hard to see a point in using apt-get here) maybe someone can see which repo is broken, else I would try deleting all files in that directory, but I'm not completely sure that would fix things.

There's a space between org/ and debian.  As in debian.org/ debian.  Was that a copy/paste error for the post, or otherwise?  Cramayar is correct in that you need to check the .list file.  Better yet, just replace it: sudo cp /usr/share/doc/apt/examples/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list

the space was a copy/past error

Folks, owe you the solution to the problem, or at least, how I solved it. From various sides I learned that mostlikely this was not a software but a hardware problem. Mostlikely the MicroSD card I used was starting to wear out, causing file/cache errors etc.
I have purchased an external NVMe-PCIe drive, flashed a completely fresh Debian distribution, followed the recipe to get the RPI4 booting from USB and copied the whole thing to the external drive.
The system runs much faster and sofar, no problems.

I suspect the entry format in your /etc/apt/sources.list is not correct.
You can try using the format rules provided by the debian team, in your case:
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates main non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates main non-free-firmware

Please take a look at debian official website on this topic.

Thanks for your time Cramayar! Now off to (regular) work but will try later. Have a good one!

Glad it was helpful @JFPJ
